# Migrating Indexes from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I am trying to migrate a database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure. I believe I have successfully migrated all of my tables and stored procedures to SQL Azure. However, when I attempt to insert a record into one of my tables, I receive an error that says:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

How do I migrate table indexes from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure. Please assume I'm stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE - This answer only applies to Web and Business editions of SQL Azure (SQL Database) - See comment below:

Unlike SQL Server 2008, SQL Azure [requires a clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#cir) to be created on every table.  If you migrated a SQL Server 2008 schema to SQL Azure that included a table without a clustered index, you'll get the error mentioned in your question.  Add a clustered index to the offending table and the insert will work just fine.

Comment: SQL Azure no longer requires a clustered index to create tables on V12 servers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396